# Compile html containing typescript code

Tags: typescript, polymer

Is there a way to compile a .html file containing embedded typescript code?

I mean a .html that has inside:

```
<script type="text/typescript">
   typescript code here 
</script>
```

I want to compile it at compile time, not runtime.

Use case is in Polymer elements, where you can have template and code in the same HTML file. With TypeScript I am obliged to split it in two files and reference the one from the other.

Answer (score 0):

In all HTML, not just polymer, you can have inline JavaScript code. It is a bad practice, though it is used in examples for brevity. The problem with this is that this practice is then carried into actual programs.

Just use:

```
<script src="relative/path/to/your/compiled/typescript.js"></script>
```

The `type="text/typescript"` attribute is only needed by `XHTML` (as apposed to `HTML5`), which I can safely assume you are not using with Polymer.

Answer (score 0):

Do do stuff like this you run the typescript compiler yourself. This has been done for you using `typescript-script` project:

https://github.com/basarat/typescript-script

Comment: but unfortunately the typescript compiler doesn't handle the case of typescript code inside of .html tags. It accepts only a pure typescript file (.ts).